# JQuery Check which radio button was unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have 4 radio inputs.

When one radio is checked a variable associated with that radio is decremented. When unchecked, the variable should be incremented.

I know that when a radio is unchecked there isn't a change event being triggered, so the code here won't work. Is there a way actually of doing this?

```
$('.radio').on('change', function() {

    // if radio is checked, decrement variable associated with radio's value
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {        
        if ($(this).val() === "int1") {
            int1--;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int2") {
            int2--;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int3") {
            int3--;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int4") {
            int4--;
        }       
    }
    // when unchecked, increment variable associated with radio's value, doesn't work!
    else {
        if ($(this).val() === "int1") {
            int1++;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int2") {
            int2++;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int3") {
            int3++;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int4") {
            int4--;
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: And how exactly does one uncheck a radio button? If there are multiple radio buttons in a group, you can just listen to the other radio buttons and increment etc.

Comment: By selecting another one, but I think you already knew that. "you can just listen to the other radio buttons and increment etc" - I don't know what that means.

Comment: Well, when you select another radio button, the one you want is unchecked. The `change` event doesn't fire when it's unchecked, but the `change` event ***is*** fired when you check one of the other buttons, so just listen for that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, try this:

```
var whichChecked = "";
$('.radio').on('change', function() {

    // if radio is checked, decrement variable associated with radio's value
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {        
        if ($(this).val() === "int1") {
            int1--;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int2") {
            int2--;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int3") {
            int3--;
        }
        if ($(this).val() === "int4") {
            int4--;
        }       

        whichChecked = $(this).val();
    }
    // when unchecked, increment variable associated with radio's value, doesn't work!

    if (whichChecked === "int1") {
        int1++;
    }
    if (whichChecked === "int2") {
        int2++;
    }
    if (whichChecked === "int3") {
        int3++;
    }
    if (whichChecked === "int4") {
        int4--;
    } 

});
```

Also consider using a couple switch statements rather than tons of if statements.

This is untested and written on a phone, but hopefully the general idea helps.

Cheers